# Entering Chords With Frescobaldi

Tags: notation, chord-progressions, lilypond, software

how do we insert chords over a melody with Frecobaldi/Lilypond?

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried in your question?

Comment: Does neither https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/single-voice nor https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/chord-notation do the trick?

Comment: example here https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/44418/how-to-align-chords-melody-and-lyrics-in-lilypond